# Unit Test Maui Does not have Maui components

Tags: unit-testing, maui

In any given code behind, Model View or Service in a Maui application, we can have something like this:

`Shell.Current.GoToAsync(shellNavigation, routeParameters)`

And at runtime, with the Maui app loaded, all is available and not injected.

But at Unit Test time, all Maui objects: App, Shell, etc. are not available, are null.

They cannot be injected or mocked, at least to my knowledge.

I tried to create a Shell or an App object on the fly but didn't seem to work. It runs but is still unavailable:

```
public AuthenticateTest()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder().UseMauiApp<App>();
    
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoginViewModel>();
    builder. Build();

    ...
    [Fact]
    public void ItShouldHaveAnAppObjectTest()
    {
       // fails because App or Shell or other components are null at this time
       CodeBehid.DoSomething() 
    }

}
```

My question, then, is:

How do I test Maui code with Maui components embedded in?

Comment: The unit-test should test the logic code such as the service. It didn't involve the UI such as the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync`.

Comment: Agreed, but if the service or mvvm or codebehind has them, then how I test around them? Cannot mock them, at some point, you  want to call the shell to change the page... or the flyout or the picker...

Comment: Maybe you need to delete the code about UI, it seems the limit of the unit test.

Comment: No, it doesn't. See the standard code, the code behind or the mvvm examples, there is a reference to the controls in the middle. Never mind, I found a way and will answer my own question shortly.

Comment: Glad to know you have fixed this problem. You can post an answer to show the details and this will help the people who meet the same problem.

Comment: @MiguelDelgado Can you post your workaround? Did you any wrapper?

Comment: I used the tools you can find at https://github.com/dotnet/maui in the dev development, the Tests for Core.
Also, this video is illuminating: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcxrmowTPrU
Basically, you create an app on the fly, with dummy static classes that mock the real controls and services.